# Ignore one Facebook wall but receive notifications for a 2nd Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

For work, I've been added as admin for a company Facebook page. I don't want to get email alerts when someone posts to the company page wall, but I do want to get alerts when someone posts to my personal wall.

Can you tell me how to implement such a configuration?

Answer (score 1):

### Stop receiving notifications from a Facebook page

1. Click on the cog in the top right of any page on Facebook
2. Click "Account Settings" from the menu that appears.
3. Click on "Notifications at the side".
4. Click "Pages You Manage"
5. Find the page you no longer want notifications from and uncheck the "On" checkbox next to it.
6. Click "Close" when you are done.
   [image]